Error in flutter assets when trying to access parent folder
I am trying to access a folder of images in Flutter this way:
assets:
    - ../backend/uploaded_images/

The first time, the app worked without any errors, but after running app again, it thrown this error on the build:
Target debug_android_application failed: FileSystemException: Cannot copy file to 'C:\Users\nuras\CS_Projects\miras\farmer_market\flutter\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\../backend/uploaded_images/13afcc89-36fb-4148-9a5c-1e47c6514bcf', path = 'C:\Users\nuras\CS_Projects\miras\farmer_market\flutter\..\backend\uploaded_images\13afcc89-36fb-4148-9a5c-1e47c6514bcf' (OS Error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect., 
errno = 123)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\nuras\dev\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                    

My guess is:

It has trouble with forward slashes and backslashes
'../' is confusing it: From the image you can see how '../' might be throwing the path off, exiting the 'flutter_assets' folder.

Please help!
Is there a way to reference a folder externally without any conflicts?
I removed the assets from .yaml and the app worked, so it is a problem with assets.

assets must be in the root folder or below.  Not above.  Rethink how you'll do this.

You have to analyze from what level of directory you're trying to access in your File Explorer, what is the absolute path of it? You can show it to us (as long as it has no sensitive information there).

Absolute path is: "C:\Users\nuras\CS_Projects\miras\farmer_market\backend\uploaded_images". But is it a good practice? Is using absolute path sustainable across devices?

If the images don't absolutely need to be there, put them in a folder inside your flutter project.Files look like this,
...
android
assets
build
lib
...

In the pubspec.yaml file write the asset exactly like this,be careful about spaces and locations.
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/backend/uploaded_images/

Once the pubspec.yaml file is ready, do

flutter pub get

and make sure to close and restart the application.

Yeah but I really need to access the other folder because that is how we constructed our system. Otherwise it is gonna mess with the other side of the program which needs images as well. And making a copy folder doesn't seem like a reliable way.
